# Rerouting in JS

Tags: javascript, url-routing

For example someone have site *"example.com"*, on it there is a button that routes me to *"example.com/xyz"* (xyz is something random), and this url routes me to another site like *"google.com"* automatically.

> *"example.com"* (button) -> *"example.com/xyz"* (routing me automatically) to ->
>   *"google.com/xyz"*

Soo until I press the button I will not know where I go.

I want to get this final url *"google.com/xyz"* from other site by request to that remote site *"example.com"*

**EDIT :**

I want to built some server side code that will return me the last routing url when I try to GET to 1st url

```
get page http://localhost/tmp/1.html
    url changed to http://localhost/tmp/2.html
get page http://localhost/tmp/2.html
    url changed to http://localhost/tmp/3.html
get page http://localhost/tmp/3.html
    url changed to http://localhost/tmp/4.html
get page http://localhost/tmp/4.html
    url changed to http://localhost/tmp/5.html
get page http://localhost/tmp/5.html

started with http://localhost/tmp/1.htmlthen
    http://localhost/tmp/2.html, then
    http://localhost/tmp/3.html, then
    http://localhost/tmp/4.html, then
    http://localhost/tmp/5.html
```

When I get 1 url it must return me the last, on my server code

Comment: check this out: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11507

Answer (score 0):

If i understand , i think you can simply use

```
window.location = "xyz.html";
```

this will redirect you to **xyz.html** in your current path

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location